# CSS and HTML mouse out?

Tags: html, css

ive been googling but cannot seem to find a mouse out method, similar to hover, for css.

Is there one and if so how should it be coded?

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. What would you expect a `mouseout` selector to do exactly?

Comment: There is a javascript event you can add to your HTML element `<a onmouseout="alert('You moved your mouse out of this text')">`

But there is no way CSS can recognise this as it is not a programming language.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  It's possible that you can achieve what you're trying to do in a different (non-javascript way).  But if you're trying to do something behavioral (as opposed to stylistic) then you'll need javascript.

Comment: Nicks answer is correct one for this.

Answer (score 6):

You only need the [`:hover` pseudo-class for this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes), when you mouse out of the element, it'll return to it's default non-`:hover` state, like this:

```
.class { color: black; } 
.class:hover { color: red; }
```

when you hover, the color will be red and when you "mouseout", the color will return to black because it no longer matches the `:hover` selector.  This is the default behavior for all browsers, nothing special you need to do here.

If you want to do something programmatic, you're looking for the [`mouseout` JavaScript event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp).

Comment: I think this is what OP was looking for, and me as well :P

Answer (score 1):

There is no mouse out event in CSS. [You need javascript in order to do that.](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/2094/css-eventselectors)

Answer (score 1):

There is the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```
element:hover { color: red }
```

there is no event or selector for when the `:hover` status ends, if that is what you're looking for.

You will have to turn to Javascript and the `onmouseout` event for that.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a mouseout-type selector for CSS.
But an element's normal style is its "mouseout" state!

What, exactly are you trying to do that normal CSS and the `:hover` selector don't cover?

Chances are, you can do it with JavaScript.  See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) or [here](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=mouseleave).

Comment: Um, probably trying to have something done only when a mouse has entered, and then left, as opposed to its normal state, which is even when the page loads, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`:hover` pseudoclass](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

```
a:hover {background: red;}
```

will highlight any link you hover over.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have the following CSS 'events' as far as I'm aware.

a (default),
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited

Comment: There are others. `:enabled`, `:disabled`, and `:checked`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There is no mouse out event but

if you want for the link you visit earlier you can use

```
a:visited{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouseout for css!

```css
div:not( :hover ){ ... }
```